# How to edit shortcode in WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

In my website there is a form which contain fields like Name, email address, Description, and a **select menu**.
now I want to change that select menu's value, but I didn't understand that in code it show only `[one_half] [/one_half]` , where is actual value store ?, where is main **html code** of that **select menu** ?

I'm not familiar with WordPress.

Comment: How that form is generating? are you using any plugins?

Comment: I developed this site from third party, so I don't know anything about it.
can you suggest which kind plugins available so I can find in Installed plugin list.

Comment: Try this plugin, https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/

Comment: Thanks @Prabu, and I saw in one demo that in any php file you can create form and give that form's reference as a short code, it is possible ?

Comment: Yes we can create custom shortcodes. Refer this link, https://www.inkthemes.com/learn-how-to-create-shortcodes-in-wordpress-plugin-with-examples/

Comment: Thank you So much.